Making relative position of annotation on gvisGeoChart fixed on different sized screens
I'm still trying to find a workaround for this question: Inserting text on either side of colorAxis in gvisGeoChart instead of numbers for Shiny app
As far as I can tell, it is not possible to (1) add a title to the color bar, or (2) remove the numbers on either side of the color bar. As a workaround, I'm trying to place annotation above it separately. My issue is that it moves drastically depending on the size as screen.
Is there a way I can fix the text to be above the color bar regardless of the screen size? For now I've positioned it so it kind of works on all but it's not as tidy as I'd like...
Very big screen: 
13 inch laptop: 
Cell phone:

The relevant code is:
    library(shiny)
    library(googleVis)
    library(dplyr)
    library(DT)
    
    # Load your data
    combined_vul_data <- 
      structure(list(ISO3 = c("AF", "AL", "DZ", "AD", "AO", "AG", "AR", 
                              "AM", "AU", "AT", "AZ", "BS", "BH", "BD", "BB", "BY", "BE", "BZ", 
                              "BJ", "BT"), Name = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", 
                                                    "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", 
                                                    "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", 
                                                    "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan"
                              ), vul_capacity_Rank_2021 = c(0.709035449, 0.511126182, 0.523332101, 
                                                            NA, 0.740026186, 0.621133795, 0.446088596, 0.462491218, 0.296565054, 
                                                            0.26689445, 0.47917568, NA, 0.453936004, 0.649876424, 0.398904506, 
                                                            0.386808093, 0.27763708, 0.547525366, 0.763503499, 0.635633065
                              )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
    
    
    # Define UI for the map
    ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .color-scale-label {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 35px;
        left: 20%;
        transform: translateX(-25%);
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        padding: 5px;
        z-index: 1000;
        pointer-events: none;
  }
      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .shiny-input-container {
          width: 100%;
        .main-panel, .content {
          height: calc(100vh - 56px) !important;
          overflow: auto;
        }
        .main-panel {
          height: 100vh;
        }
      }
    "))
  ),
     titlePanel(div(span("Country Rankings"), style={'padding-top: 15px'})),
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Vulnerability Map",
                 sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(
                     selectInput("year", "Select Year", choices = 2021, selected = 2021),
                     selectInput("category", "Select Category", 
                                 choices = list("Adaptive Capacity" = "vul_capacity"), selected = "vul_vulnerability")
                   ),
                   mainPanel(
                     tags$div(class="color-scale-label", "Least to Most Vulnerable"),
                     htmlOutput("map")
                   )
                 )
        )
      )
    )
    
    # Define server logic for the map
    server <- function(input, output) {
       output$map <- renderGvis({
        year <- input$year
        category <- input$category
        
        # Create the column name for the selected year and category
        rank_column <- paste(category, "_Rank_", year, sep = "")
        
        # Filter and prepare the data
        map_data <- combined_vul_data %>%
          select(ISO3, Name, Rank = !!sym(rank_column)) %>%
          mutate(Tooltip = ifelse(is.na(Rank), paste(Name, "- Insufficient data"), paste(Name)))
        
        # Update locationvar column
        map_data <- map_data %>%
          mutate(Location = ifelse(Name %in% c("Congo (Brazzaville)", "Congo (Kinshasa)"), ISO3, Name))
        
        # Determine the range of the Rank values
        min_rank <- min(map_data$Rank, na.rm = TRUE)
        max_rank <- max(map_data$Rank, na.rm = TRUE)
        
        # Create the map
        gvisGeoChart(map_data, locationvar = "Location", colorvar = "Rank",
                     hovervar = "Tooltip",  
                     options = list(colorAxis = paste0("{minValue:", min_rank, ", maxValue:", max_rank, ", colors:['#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FF0000']}"),
                                    backgroundColor = '#81d4fa', datalessRegionColor = '#f5f5f5',
                                    defaultColor = '#f5f5f5',
                                    tooltip = "{isHtml: true}",
                                    width = "100%",
                                    height = "500px"))  
      })
      
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


There doesn't appear to be anything useful for this endeavor in the googleVis library, however there are infinite possibilities of what you could do with JS.
You mentioned getting rid of the values; you also mentioned adding a title. This answer entails how to add a title of which is placed and sized based on the current colorbar content.

I didn't include your styles in the head. You can, of course, add them back, there won't be any conflicts with what I've written.

There is javascript in the head that is used to identify where the colorbar is and how big it is.
In that JS, the first 2 lines with the function addSVG() contain elements you may want to change.

the title (currently set to title = 'Least to Most Vulnerable';)
the value found on the left side of the toolbar (currently round(min(combined_vul_data$vul_capacity_Rank_2021, na.rm = T), 3))

The last line in the function addSVG() contains $('#putItHere').html(svgu);  where putItHere is identical to the ID called in the UI (currently tags$div(id = "putItHere", style = css(position = "absolute", width = "100%", top = 0))) --- if you change one, you've got to change the other.
I've added a lot of comments in the content that I added to your code, but if you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask.
The data and server are unchanged (I only have the UI here.)
# Define UI for the map
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(
      paste0(
        "window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
      setTimeout(function() {   /* ensure entire SVG has loaded before executing */
        addSVG();
      }, 1000);

      function addSVG() {        
        title = 'Least to Most Vulnerable';     /* title to add to the plot */      
        where = $('g text:contains(", round(min(combined_vul_data$vul_capacity_Rank_2021, na.rm = T), 3), ")'); 
                                                /* identify where to position the title */
        w = Math.floor($('g text:contains(0.267)')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width * 6);
        h = $('g text:contains(0.267)')[0].getBoundingClientRect().height * 2;
    
        newSz = Number(where[0].getAttribute('font-size')) * 1.5;  /* used to determine title spacing height */
        getA = where[0].outerHTML;                                 /* get element attributes- white background */
        getB = where[1].outerHTML;                                 /* get element attributes- black text */
        newA = getA.replace(/(?<=(y=\"))([0-9.]+)/g, newSz);       /* update y position for title */
        newB = getB.replace(/(?<=(y=\"))([0-9.]+)/g, newSz);       /* update y position for title */
        newTa = newA.replace(/(?<=(\\>))[0-9.]+/g, title);         /* Add title */
        newTb = newB.replace(/(?<=(\\>))[0-9.]+/g, title);         /* Add title */
                                                                   /* create SVG element */
        newE = '<svg width=\"' + w + '\" height=\"' + h + '\" viewBox=\"0 0 ' + w + ' ' + h + '\" transform=\"translate(0, ' + 
                   Math.floor((Number(where[0].getAttribute('y')) - h) * 0.98) + ')\">';
    
        svgu = newE + '<g>' + newTa + newTb + '</g></svg>';         /* assemble SVG content */
        $('#putItHere').html(svgu);                                 /* add to page; output$NAME in Shiny app */
      }
    });"))
    )),
  titlePanel(div(span("Country Rankings"), style={'padding-top: 15px'})),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Vulnerability Map",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 selectInput("year", "Select Year", choices = 2021, selected = 2021),
                 selectInput("category", "Select Category", 
                             choices = list("Adaptive Capacity" = "vul_capacity"), selected = "vul_vulnerability")
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 # tags$div(class="color-scale-label", "Least to Most Vulnerable"),
                 htmlOutput("map"),
                 tags$div(id = "putItHere", style = css(position = "absolute", width = "100%", top = 0))
               )
             )
    )
  )
)

A few perspectives:

 
